# How to use data in CSV file for Soap XML request in Karate framework

Tags: xml, csv, soap, karate

I am tried scenario outline with inbuilt table examples within scenario and it worked well. But ask from my team is to have more number of examples using external excel sheet. So instead of Excel and trying to have it as CSV file for Test data. But tried using csv file with the examples available in Github and failed with those examples. As am not a programmer not sure on the mistake I made. 
Below is the scenario Outline,

```
     Feature: Feature1

    Background:

    * url ''
    * configure logPrettyRequest = true
    * configure logPrettyResponse = true 

Scenario Outline: 1   
        * def look= read('../utils/look.xml')

        * replace look

            | token        | value     |

            | @@number@@   | < number> |

            | @@country@@  |< country>| 

        Given url 'baseurl'

        And request look

        When method post

        Then status 200

        Examples:

        |read('name.csv')|

But while running this script console logs as :
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.78 s - [INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

CSV file contents:name.csv

number,country

895201301,173
```

Issue: No scenarios identified as part of this run

Please suggest way to use CSV file for Test data under scenario Outline of Karate.

Comment: You are updating the variable "look", but requesting with variable "lookup".

Comment: Sorry it was a typo while posting this. Edited to "Look" now. Scenarios not identified due to some mistake in refering csv file I guess. Someone Please help.

Comment: the only suggestion I have is to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas Can you please re-confirm whether Examples |read('name.csv'| I gave in the scenario outline is the right way to refer CSV file in Karate Framework for XML request??

Comment: @Anithasub based on the severely limited information here - yes

Comment: Ok sure Peter I will try submitting an issue as per guidelines :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues: The extra space in front of the number and country placeholders has to be removed. Also, the placeholders should be enclosed in quotes.

**Sample Code:**

```
Feature: Feature1

    Background:
        * url ''
        * configure logPrettyRequest = false
        * configure logPrettyResponse = false

    Scenario Outline: <number>,<country>
        * def look = "@@number@@,@@country@@"
        * replace look
            | token       | value       |
            | @@number@@  | '<number>'  |
            | @@country@@ | '<country>' |
        * print look

        Examples:
            | read('name.csv') |
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, two points, can you try to add single quotes to all data in your csv file if not already done. Intead of 'replace' can you try to use set method to set the values on the fly. Please let me know if this helps